# Python Nested For Loops With Match/Update Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am writing a script in python which loops two tables against each other. If a condition is met then the script will make an update on the dependent table.

My python code so far:

```
def updatedata():
    for y in range(updatetable.shape[0]):
        for x in range(mastertable.shape[0]):
            if updatetable[y].s_date <= mastertable[x].index <= updatetable[y].e_date:
                mastertable[x].field2 = updatetable[y]. field2
                mastertable[y].field3 = updatetable[y]. field3
```

I also have this iteration technique:

```
for index, row in mastertable.iterrows():
    print (row['Value'], index)

for index, row in updatetable.iterrows():
    print (row['field1'], row['field2'])
```

I am following how I would write this in VBA:

```
For x = 1 to lastrow_update
    for y = 1 to lastrow_master
        if update(x,1) <= master(y,1) and master(y,1) <= update(x,2) then
        master (y,2) = update(x,3)
```

I am getting errors with the python code.
1) how do I create two control variables for the "for loops"
2) how do I exit the inner loop after a match to cut down on run time

error for def updatedata()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/project4.py", line 41, in <module>
    updatedata()
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/project4.py", line 20, in updatedata
    if presidents_data[y].tookoffice <= sp500[x].index <= presidents_data[y].leftoffice:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

sample of data:

```
               president tookoffice leftoffice       party
0      Lyndon B. Johnson 1963-11-22 1969-01-20  Democratic
1  Franklin D. Roosevelt 1933-03-04 1945-04-12  Democratic
2         Herbert Hoover 1929-03-04 1933-03-04  Republican
3      Warren G. Harding 1921-03-04 1923-08-02  Republican
4           Barack Obama 2009-01-20 2017-01-20  Democratic
            Value  president  party_of_president
Date                                            
1871-01-01   4.44  president  party_of_president
1871-02-01   4.50  president  party_of_president
1871-03-01   4.61  president  party_of_president
1871-04-01   4.74  president  party_of_president
1871-05-01   4.86  president  party_of_president
```

Comment: @klutt please see the updated post

Comment: If your tables are dataframes you shouldn't use a for loop to update, you can use something like: `updatetable.loc[(updatetable['s_date'] <= mastertable.index) & (mastertable.index <= updatetable['e_date']), 'field2'] = mastertable['field2']` to update `updatetable` if a certain condition is met. Can you post a sample of each table (i.e. `updatetable.head()`)?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry - updated the post with a data sample. I am working with your line of code right now.

Answer (score 0):

When indexing by rows using an integer index, you need `.iloc`:

```
if updatetable.iloc[y].s_date <= mastertable.iloc[x].index <= updatetable.iloc[y].e_date:
```

The syntax updatetable.iloc[y] means "get the column called y", in which case y should be "president" or another string for which you have a column.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pandas's [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) (i.e., "interval merge") using the backward direction for *tookoffice* or equivalently forward direction with *leftoffice*:

```
merge_df = pd.merge_asof(value_df, pres_df, left_on='Date', right_on='tookoffice', 
                         suffixes=['','_'], direction='backward')


merge_df = pd.merge_asof(value_df, pres_df, left_on='Date', right_on='leftoffice', 
                         suffixes=['','_'], direction='forward')
```

Below is demonstration using random data, mirroring posted data. For below solution, two things must done:

1. president dataframes's *tookoffice* and *leftoffice* must be sorted;
2. value dataframe's index should be reset to have *Date* as a column in dataframe (set back at end).

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

txt = '''
               president tookoffice leftoffice       party
0      "Lyndon B. Johnson" "1963-11-22" "1969-01-20"  Democratic
1  "Franklin D. Roosevelt" "1933-03-04" "1945-04-12"  Democratic
2         "Herbert Hoover" "1929-03-04" "1933-03-04"  Republican
3      "Warren G. Harding" "1921-03-04" "1923-08-02"  Republican
4           "Barack Obama" "2009-01-20" "2017-01-20"  Democratic'''


pres_df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=[0], 
                        parse_dates=['tookoffice', 'leftoffice'])

pres_df = pres_df.sort_values(['tookoffice', 'leftoffice'])


np.random.seed(7012018)   # SEEDED FOR REPRODUCIBILITY
value_df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': 4 + abs(np.random.randn(1765)),
                         'president': 'president',
                         'party_of_president': 'party_of_president'},
                        columns=['Value', 'president', 'party_of_president'],
                        index=pd.date_range('1871-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq='MS'))\
                       .rename_axis('Date')

value_df = value_df.reset_index()
```

**Merge**

```
merge_df = pd.merge_asof(value_df, pres_df, left_on='Date', right_on='tookoffice', 
                         suffixes=['','_'], direction='backward')

# UPDATE NEEDED COLUMNS TO ADJACENT COLUMNS
merge_df['president'] = merge_df['president_']
merge_df['party_of_president'] = merge_df['party']

merge_df['president'] = merge_df['president_']
merge_df['party_of_president'] = merge_df['party']

# CLEAN UP (IN CASE PRESIDENT DF IS NOT EXHAUSTIVE BETWEEN 1871-2018)
mask = ~merge_df['Date'].between(merge_df['tookoffice'], merge_df['leftoffice'])

merge_df.loc[mask, 'president'] = np.nan
merge_df.loc[mask, 'party_of_president'] = np.nan

# SUBSET FIRST 4 COLUMNS AND SET INDEX
merge_df = merge_df[merge_df.columns[:4]].set_index('Date')
```

**Output**

```
print(merge_df.shape)    # SAME SHAPE AS ORIGINAL value_df
# (1765, 3)


# FIRST 20 RECORDS
print(merge_df.head(20))   
#                Value president party_of_president
# Date                                             
# 1871-01-01  4.859688       NaN                NaN
# 1871-02-01  4.309355       NaN                NaN
# 1871-03-01  5.003074       NaN                NaN
# 1871-04-01  4.769772       NaN                NaN
# 1871-05-01  5.765133       NaN                NaN
# 1871-06-01  5.408663       NaN                NaN
# 1871-07-01  4.177684       NaN                NaN
# 1871-08-01  5.980318       NaN                NaN
# 1871-09-01  5.029296       NaN                NaN
# 1871-10-01  4.604133       NaN                NaN
# 1871-11-01  4.691276       NaN                NaN
# 1871-12-01  5.387712       NaN                NaN
# 1872-01-01  4.387162       NaN                NaN
# 1872-02-01  4.002513       NaN                NaN
# 1872-03-01  6.105690       NaN                NaN
# 1872-04-01  5.604589       NaN                NaN
# 1872-05-01  4.860393       NaN                NaN
# 1872-06-01  4.776127       NaN                NaN
# 1872-07-01  4.280952       NaN                NaN
# 1872-08-01  4.886334       NaN                NaN


# FIRST NON-NULL VALUES
print(merge_df[~pd.isnull(merge_df['president'])].head(20))
#                Value          president party_of_president
# Date                                                      
# 1921-04-01  5.713479  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-05-01  4.542561  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-06-01  5.148667  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-07-01  4.949704  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-08-01  5.138469  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-09-01  5.797446  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-10-01  4.498131  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-11-01  4.216718  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1921-12-01  6.110533  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-01-01  5.179318  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-02-01  4.808477  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-03-01  4.466641  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-04-01  4.307025  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-05-01  4.337476  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-06-01  4.396854  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-07-01  4.391316  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-08-01  4.748302  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-09-01  5.468115  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-10-01  4.295268  Warren G. Harding         Republican
# 1922-11-01  5.432448  Warren G. Harding         Republican
```

Comment: is there any reason this wouldn't work?def updatedata():
    `for y in range(presidents_data.shape[0]):
        update = sp500[presidents_data.iloc[y].tookoffice:presidents_data.iloc[y].leftoffice]
        sp500.loc[update['party_of_president']] == presidents_data['party']`

Comment: getting a [None of .. are in the [index]]